# Angular async data checking issue

Tags: http, authentication, angularjs

My service looks like

```
//this mthod under myService
this.checkCookie = this.getAuthorization = function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/auth'
    });
}
```

And in my route configuration I am doing like

```
MyAPP.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: check
    }).

    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',
        controller: check


    }).
    when('/products', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/products.html'
    })
});

var check = function($location, myService, $q) {
        if (myService.checkCookie()) {
            $location.path("/products");
        } else {
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    };
```

with  get request I want to check session data generated by the server is valid or not. And browser will send the cookie information while sending 'GET' in '/api/auth'.

The problem is when I am calling  this.checkCookie I am not getting the response syncronoulsy as angular returns response in asnyc fashion. Depending on the checkCookie response I am suppose to redirect to '/products' but I cant do that now.

How can I do that? What I need to change to get this.checkCookie and check whether the response status is 200 or 500?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do synchronous requests with `$http`. To handle the promise return by the request, you can do this:

```
var check = function($location, myService, $q) {
  myService.checkCookie()
   .success(function() {
     $location.path("/products");
   })
   .error(function() {
     $location.path("/login");
   })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `then` on the promise that's returned from `$http`:

```
myService.checkCookie().then(function () {
    $location.path("/products");
}, function () {
    $location.path("/login");
});
```

The first function is the success handler, and the second one is the error (reject) handler.